# Covering exposed insulation paper face

Tags: insulation

Other than gypsum, what else can be put over exposed insulation? Code wont allow for exposed paper. If not tyvek than what specific product can be used? The company that installed my insulation, which failed final inspection won't return calls.  I was told nonwoven flame retardant sheet.  Anyone have specific product that meets that?

Comment: Is changing the insulation out for a non-faced product not acceptable here?

Comment: What is your question? Clear things up.. Why did i fail  , my dad had paper faced to close to wood stove and AHJ saw it and helped resolve it..

Comment: Question is what non-woven flame resistant membrane or product could the county home inspector have been referring to?

It failed because code states that the kraft paper cannot be a exposed.  Replacing isnt really an option as too much to replace.  It would be my last option but then i would need a vapor barrier and right back at same problem.  The building codes have gotten ridiculous but must be followed

Comment: I think poly is acceptable it is in my location and much cheaper than Tyvek,  is it required to be woven? Haven’t seen that one yet.

Comment: What country/city/state are you in?  Where is the insulation in the structure?  Do you plan to put anything over the insulation, like drywall?  How is the rest of that wall built?  I wouldn't recommend a vapor barrier like poly on an interior wall in a warm, wet, or mixed area. A vapor retarder will still allow the moisture to evaporate and the wall to dry out, while a vapor barrier will retain the moisture, possibly leading to mold and wood rot. Ask the inspector what products he would or wouldn't recommend for this and let us know. The more we know, the better answer we can give.

Answer (score 1):

Flame-retardant polyethylene (6 mil, I think) is commonly used. You'd sort of end up with a double vapor barrier, but since they're tight together it's probably not a problem. It's readily available at building materials suppliers.

Regarding your "ridiculous codes" comment, walls of highly-flammable paper are a genuine safety concern. It ignites much more readily than the paper on the face of drywall, for example, and spreads flame very quickly. Surely you prefer that the occupants have a fighting chance at survival, and those [downward-trending lines](https://www.usfa.fema.gov/data/statistics/fire_death_rates.html#death_rate) don't happen by accident.

Comment: I have used poly to separate attic spaces that did not require fire walls (not defined as living spaces). I wonder about the “woven” part but plastic has worked for me in the past.+ I need to read the answers before commenting.

Comment: Thanks all!  I am in northern virginia.  The issue is in the attic and part of the basement.  55’ long of room trusses for storage but non-living space.  Going to see if inspector can name some of the products.  The folks at home depot and lowes were clueless of sich

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how this site works.